# Unreferenced object error with parallel invoke method

Tags: c#, object, reference, parallel-processing

I have a problem not referenced object if called with parallel.invoke , the problem is that if you call them one by one the methods , they work .

```
try
        {
            Task t1 = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                log.Info("call GetRecentHomeChanges");
                GetRecentHomeChanges resultHomeChanges = await apManager.GetRecentHomeChanges(ApplicationContext.Instance.LoggedUser.UserName, ApplicationContext.Instance.LoggedUser.HashedPwd);
                ApplicationContext.Instance.pastmeetingList = resultHomeChanges.PastMeetings;
                ApplicationContext.Instance.documentsHomePageList = resultHomeChanges.Attachments;
            });
            Task t2 = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                //STORED PROCEDURE CALL - INSERISCO I PAST MEETINGS
                storedProcedure.insertPastMeetings(ApplicationContext.Instance.LoggedUser.PID, ApplicationContext.Instance.pastmeetingList);
                List<PastMeetings> pastMeetingsDB = storedProcedure.selectPastMeetings(ApplicationContext.Instance.LoggedUser.PID);
                ApplicationContext.Instance.pastmeetingList = pastMeetingsDB;
            });

            await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

if I call them so they work regularly :

```
        log.Info("call GetRecentHomeChanges");
        GetRecentHomeChanges resultHomeChanges = await apManager.GetRecentHomeChanges(ApplicationContext.Instance.LoggedUser.UserName, ApplicationContext.Instance.LoggedUser.HashedPwd);
        ApplicationContext.Instance.pastmeetingList = resultHomeChanges.PastMeetings;
        ApplicationContext.Instance.documentsHomePageList = resultHomeChanges.Attachments;

        //STORED PROCEDURE CALL - INSERISCO I PAST MEETINGS
        storedProcedure.insertPastMeetings(ApplicationContext.Instance.LoggedUser.PID, ApplicationContext.Instance.pastmeetingList);
        List<PastMeetings> pastMeetingsDB = storedProcedure.selectPastMeetings(ApplicationContext.Instance.LoggedUser.PID);
        ApplicationContext.Instance.pastmeetingList = pastMeetingsDB;
```

So my problem occurs only when calling in parallel , and the printed error code is : { " Object reference not set to an instance of an object . " }

how can i solve ?

Comment: What's the point of that `try...catch...throw` beside getting rid of the call stack?

Comment: the point is on the storeProcedure.insertPastMeetings

Comment: Task 2 seems to assume there is already something set to ApplicationContext.Instance.pastmeetingList, if this is not the case this seems like a valid action - if you're running in parallell task2 may fire and not have anything set to that when it starts.. Seems reasonable

Comment: Parallelizing code requires that code to be thread-safe.  That doesn't happen very often, many ways in which such code can fail.  Pretty hard to guess what that code does but it certainly doesn't look safe, a variable like *pastmeetingList* is doomed to misbehave since you both read and write it without any lock in multiple threads.  That just can't work.  If t2 races ahead of t1 then klaboom on variable still being null.  This is guaranteed to happen sooner or later, you are very lucky to get it sooner.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `ApplicationContext.Instance.pastmeetingList` in the first threadpool task, and reading `ApplicationContext.Instance.pastmeetingList` in the second threadpool task. By executing both of these in parallel, you're telling your code to read and write the variable at the same time. Hopefully it's obvious that this won't work if the read takes place before the write.

So, this code can't be parallelized.